# d3.js and svg: panning while zoomed in/out doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, zooming

I have a map I've drawn in an SVG using d3, and the SVG is inside a viewbox, something like:

```
<svg id="mapcanvas" class="map-svg flow" viewBox="60 -20 800 500">

    <defs>...</defs>
    <g class="zoomgroup" transform="translate(300,162.02921295166016)scale(0.5)">
        <rect class="mapocean" width="150%" height="150%" y="-150"></rect>
        <g class="mapgroup">
            <path class="country AF" ...>
            ...
```

I've done the standard pan/zoom set up, which sets the transform attribute of the `<g class="zoomgroup">`.  The code (slightly cleaned up) is:

```
// zoomg is a d3 object represent the <g class="zoomgroup"> above
var setupZoom = function(zoomg) {
    var zoomed = function() {
        var translate = d3.event.translate,
            scale = d3.event.scale;
        translate[0] = Math.max(-600*scale, Math.min(600*scale, translate[0]));
        translate[1] = Math.max(-350*scale, Math.min(350*scale, translate[1]));

        zoomg.attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
    },
    zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .translate([0, 0])
        .scale(1)
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 20])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
    zoomg.call(zoom);
}
```

The [full code at this commit is on github](https://github.com/trademapper/trademapper-js/tree/22c12a76dc04512dae80f0158c858ebb244394be).

Zooming works fine, as does panning when you are at the initial scale.

When you are zoomed in (scale > 1) panning is "slow" - the mouse moves further than the map does, and it gets worse the further you are zoomed in.

When you are zoomed out (scale < 1) the d3.event.translate numbers can easily reach 15000 or so, at which point the map is way outside the screen.  (That is why I added the min/max code, to stop the map disappearing).

So I really don't understand what the d3.event.translate numbers are doing or how they're being generated, and how that relates to the viewbox.  Should I be adding x() and y() functions in the d3.behaviour.zoom() call?  If so what should those functions be?

So can you help me get a smooth panning effect while zoomed in or out?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `svg.call(zoom);` instead of `zoomg.call(zoom);`.

Comment: Do you mean I should be zooming the entire SVG rather than just a `<g>` element?  I did deliberately want to only zoom one element of the SVG - is it the case that D3 zooming/panning only works with the entire SVG then?  I could refactor the app to be a few different SVGs if that is the only way.